# Hi we have a iPad Need to reset

Tags: icloud

We have forgotten pass codes to iCloud and need to update ect.... Any help to over ride this would be great. Apple can't help as we don't remember secrete questions

Comment: Instructions how to hack a passcode are available on this website http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/80-of-the-most-useful-mac-tools-and-utilities/

Answer (score 1):

Forgotten Apple ID/iCloud passwords can be recovered at http://iforgot.apple.com/. If you don't know the answer to any of the security questions any longer and can not prove your identity to Apple in any other way, you may be out of luck.